# Trying to set the first text of a combobox with dropdownlist style C#

Tags: drop-down-menu, combobox

```
combobox.text = "blabla";
```

doesnt work

```
combobox.SelectedValue = number;
```

doesn't work

I'm trying to set a text like "select an item" on a dropdownlist style combobox, nothing i've read so far actually works, because i set it like a dropdownlist (works as a read-only combobox)

any hint?

Answer (score 0):

It actually works, I was just misplacing the code

```
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        combobox.text = "blabla";

     }
```

As long as item blabla exists in the collection, it will display.